# Moving from Windows Install to full install for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 inside windows but would now like to do a full install. Is this a matter of uninstall and reinstall or is there a short cut given that all updates are downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make a Wubi install the only OS.
I am assuming you used the Wubi installer. Because you used Wubi, which installs inside Windows like a program, you need to do a complete install.

1.) Back up all of your data (e.g. Dropbox, Google Drive, USB key, SSD, etc.). This method will completely format your hard disk.

2.) Download the appropriate Ubuntu .iso from [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

3.) Use the built in function inside Windows to burn the .iso to an DVD.

4.) After you have burnt the .iso to the disc, completely shut down your machine and boot into the Ubuntu install DVD you have just burnt.

5.) Follow the instructions to install. If it detects Windows 7, tell it to erase it. It is up to you if you want to encrypt.

6.) Enjoy Ubuntu!